# Raspberry Pi4 に Ubuntu 19.10 をインストールしたがキーボード入力ができない

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

Raspberry Pi4 4GBにUbuntu Server 19.10を書き込んだmicroSDを挿入し起動したのですが、下記の画像の状態で止まってしまい、キーボードを押してもなにも表示されません。
何が原因なのでしょうか?

Unixのpasswordコマンドの様に、表示されないだけかもしれないと思いEnterを押してみましたが何も変わりませんでした。

また、Ubuntu19.10にはバグがあり、4GBのモデルではUSBが動かなくなっていたのですがこれも修正されたようです。(Ubuntuイメージは2019/12/2にダウンロードしたものを使っています)

なぜ止まってしまうのでしょうか?

Comment: 画像が添付されていないようです。

Comment: 先ほどからuploadを試しているのですがエラーでうまく行かないのです。

Comment: むむ、そうでしたか。もし少し待っても問題が再現するようでしたら、[メタ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)に投稿いただければ何かしらのバグが見つかるかもしれません。念のため英語版 Stack Overflow の Meta と Meta Stack Exchange を確認してきたのですが、そちらでは現在問題が報告されていませんでした。今私がアップロードを試したところできたので、何かしら環境依存の問題かもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
Raspberry Pi4 4GBでのみ起こるUSBのバグがあり、現時点(2019/12/3)ではまだ修正されていないようです。

[USB not working under arm64 on Pi4 with 4G ram](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi2/+bug/1848790)

Answer (score 1):

[@KiYugadgeter さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/61035/3060) のリンク先でコメント欄にてワークアラウンドが載っています。

usercfg.txt ファイルでメモリ使用量を少な目に制限することで、問題の起きている環境でも動作するようになる、という話の様です。

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi2/+bug/1848790/comments/9

> Setting total_mem=2048 in /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt allowed me to boot Pi4 4GB with 19.10 64bit
>   with working USB. Of course I have less RAM now, but working USB.